# How does Continuous Deployment work with Web App For Containers when using multi-containers?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

How does Continuous Deployment work with multi-containers on Web App For Containers? With a single container, App Service will pull the container when an update is pushed to Azure Container Registry using the WebHook but how does that work with multi-containers? Will the WebHook will be triggered by any container updates? Will all containers be updated?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ci-cd) does not mention the multi-containers scenario.

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it. Or for more help please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Multi containers in Docker means the docker-compose. You can also use [the compose on Azure with Web App for Multi Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app). There is a Continuous Deployment setting for the compose. Although the compose is in the preview version.

**Update**

For the WebHook of Azure Container Registry, it triggers events when certain actions take place in one of your registry repositories. No matter where you use the docker images if the images change the webhook work.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that.  This is not was I'm asking, read my question again.

Comment: Thanks Charles.  Let's see if I got that right: If have 3 containers and 1 gets updated, the Webhook will trigger a global update and since only 1 was changed, App Service will only pull that one.  Right?

Comment: Yeah, as the document say, there just the image which you tragged changes when it get update.